# findContours function error in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, error-handling

I am trying to run the following code (posting only a part of it)

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global variables
Mat erosion_dst, dilation_dst,adt,dst;
Mat threshold_output;

int erosion_elem = 0;
int erosion_size = 15;
int dilation_elem = 0;
int dilation_size = 0;
int const max_elem = 2;
int const max_kernel_size = 21;

/** Function Headers */
void Erosion( int, void* );
void Dilation( int, void* );

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
Mat denoised,blur_image;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

// Function header
//void thresh_callback(int, void* );

vector<vector<Point> > contours;

vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles


/* @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{   
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();


    int count; 
    char *outText;


    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread("swine.jpg");
    fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(src, denoised,10,10,7,21 );

    GaussianBlur(denoised,blur_image,Size(5,5),0,0);
    // Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor(blur_image, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );


    // Create Window
    //char* source_window = "Source";
    //namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    //imshow( source_window, src );
    adaptiveThreshold(src_gray, adt, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2);
    imwrite("Adaptive_thresholding.tif",adt);

    //Erosion
    Erosion(0,0);

    //Thresholding for contours
    //createTrackbar( " Threshold:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
    //thresh_callback( 0, 0 );
    // Detect edges using Threshold
    threshold( erosion_dst, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );

    // Find contours
    imwrite("thresh_out.jpg",threshold_output);
    findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
    vector<Point2f> ContArea(contours.size());
```

Now, when I try to compile the above, it gives me the following error:

```
test_rect.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test_rect.cpp:88:55: error: ‘CV_RETR_TREE’ was not declared in this scope
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
                                                       ^
test_rect.cpp:88:69: error: ‘CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE’ was not declared in this scope
  findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

Now, I tried searching for the solution and one post suggested changing the first two include headers to search for the current directory by using `<>` instead of double quotes. But this didn't help. Therefore, I am posting it here if anyone can help me out with it. Thanks!

Comment: Wierd... Try removing the "CV_"...  So "RETR_TREE" etc...

Comment: That's a bizarre error indeed.

Comment: @Miki that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're using latest version of opencv then remove CV from CV_RETR_TREE and CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE.
click here for more details https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html